# Using .Select and .Where in a single LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, unique, distinct

I need to gather Distinct Id's from a particular table using LINQ. The catch is I also need a WHERE statement that should filter the results based only from the requirements I've set. Relatively new to having to use LINQ so much, but I'm using the following code more or less:

```
private void WriteStuff(SqlHelper db, EmployeeHelper emp)
{
    String checkFieldChange;
    AnIList tableClass = new AnIList(db, (int)emp.PersonId);
    var linq = tableClass.Items
        .Where(
           x => x.UserId == emp.UserId 
             && x.Date > DateBeforeChanges 
             && x.Date < DateAfterEffective 
             && (
                     (x.Field == Inserted)
                  || (x.Field == Deleted)))
                )
             ).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);

    if (linq != null)
    {
        foreach (TableClassChanges item in linq)
        {
            AnotherIList payTxn = new AnotherIList(db, item.Id);
            checkFieldChange = GetChangeType(item.FieldName);

            // Other codes that will retrieve data from each item 
            // and write it into a text file
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add .Distinct for var linq but it's still returning duplicate items (meaning having the same Id's). I've read through a lot of sites and have tried adding a .Select into the query but the .Where clause breaks instead. There are other articles where the query is somehow different with the way it retrieves the values and place it in a var. I also tried to use .GroupBy but I get an "At least one object must implement IComparable" when using Id as a key.

The query actually works and I'm able to output the data from the columns with the specifications I require, but I just can't seem to make .Distinct work (which is the only thing really missing). I tried to create two vars with one triggering a distinct call then have a nested foreach to ensure the values are just unique, but will thousands of records to gather the performance impact is just too much.

I'm unsure as well if I'd have to override or use IEnumerable for my requirement, and thought I'd ask the question around just in case there's an easier way, or if it's possible to have both .Select and .Where working in just one statement?

Comment: Your question seems to imply that there are multiple rows in the table with the same id, but different data -- which is not exactly logical. Please clarify what your data looks like and exactly what's going on with the ids.

Comment: Hi Jon, that's actually correct. The Id here is a transaction ID, and tracks all that has been changed to a particular user in a single command (i.e. fields a, b, and c were edited via this transaction ID). I need to Distinct it though as the only data required is the latest row updated to that particular user, so regardless if there are multiple edits in that single transaction, only the most recent change is required.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order for [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) to work for your type, you can implement `IEquatable<T>` and provide suitable definitions for `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, otherwise it will use the default implementation: comparing for reference equality (assuming that you are using a reference type).

From the manual:

> The Distinct(IEnumerable) method returns an unordered sequence that contains no duplicate values. It uses the default equality comparer, Default, to compare values.
>
> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.

In your case it looks like you might just need to compare the IDs, but you may also want to compare other fields too depending on what it means for you that two objects are "the same".

You can also consider using [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Note that this is LINQ to Objects only, but I assume that's what you are using.

Yet another option is to combine `GroupBy` and `First`:

```
 var query = // your query here...
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

This would also work in LINQ to SQL, for example.

Comment: I've wanted to use morelinq when I found it this morning but was not allowed to include it in the solution. Taking a look at the groupby and first option now.

Answer (score 77):

Did you add the `Select()` after the `Where()` or before?

You should add it after, because of the concurrency logic:

```
 1 Take the entire table  
 2 Filter it accordingly  
 3 Select only the ID's  
 4 Make them distinct.
```

If you do a Select first, the Where clause can only contain the ID attribute because all other attributes have already been edited out.

Update: For clarity, this order of operators should work:

```
db.Items.Where(x=> x.userid == user_ID).Select(x=>x.Id).Distinct();
```

Probably want to add a `.toList()` at the end but that's optional :)

Comment: Actually I tried this approach and I get an ArgumentException whenever the Select is added (At least one object must implement IComparable)

Comment: This helped me, was just looking for a simple SELECT with a WHERE.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to compare two different objects you will need to first implement the IEqualityComparer interface. Here is an example code on a simple console application that uses distinct and a simple implementation of the IEqualityComparer:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Test> testData = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test(1,"Test"),
            new Test(2, "Test"),
            new Test(2, "Test")
        };

        var result = testData.Where(x => x.Id > 1).Distinct(new MyComparer());
    }
}

public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
{
    public bool Equals(Test x, Test y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Test obj)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", obj.Id, obj.Name).GetHashCode();
    }
}


public class Test
{
    public Test(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I've actually tried this upon reading on other links as well as the rest of the IEqualityComparer. The issue however is that I'd be performing the same logic on other tables as well, and it's not always the case that the column of comparison is Id. I can take this approach but I fear it's going to take more time than I would have to sort it out for all the tables that I'll be interacting with.

Comment: You can have your tables to implement a common base class with just the property that is the same for them. This way you will be able to write comparers based on the base class and not on each table. So for example if you have 10 tables that have ID and 20 tables that have FirstName you will only have to write two comparers based on the two base classes (one containing the ID proeprty and the other containing the FirstName).

Answer (score 1):

Do you passed a `IEqualityComparer<T>` to `.Distinct()`?

Something like this:

```
internal abstract class BaseComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> {
    public bool Equals(T x, T y) {
        return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
    }

    public abstract int GetHashCode(T obj);
}

internal class DetailComparer : BaseComparer<StyleFeatureItem> {
    public override int GetHashCode(MyClass obj) {
        return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
list.Distinct(new DetailComparer())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily query with LINQ like this

considering this JSON

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "two"
        }
    ]
}
```

putting it in a variable called `json` like this,

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse("{'items':[{'id':'10','name':'one'},{'id':'12','name':'two'}]}");
```

you  can select all ids from the items where name is `"one"` using the following LINQ query

```
var Ids =
    from item in json["items"]
    where (string)item["name"] == "one"
    select item["id"];
```

Then, you will have the result in an IEnumerable list